# Paypal payment for access to restricted area

Tags: payment, paypal

I'd like to set up a part of my site as a 'restricted' area that you need to pay via Paypal to access. Can anyone offer some advice on how to do this? Ideally I'd like to have a 'subscribed' value in my database that I can check when people attempt to access the site to check if they have subscribed. I've started looking into IPN which might be the way to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a new store that will integrate with PayPal. From what I've read, yes, IPN seems like the way to do it. Have a Subscribe button, and when you receive an IPN message that indicates successful payment, update the user's 'subscribed' field. I think IPN also sends a message when their subscription runs out.